# Thread Java application

Tags: java

I have to build a **java** application which return the names of pdf files in Directory and SubDirictory using threads and it had done.
but in addition I've to print it with un alphabetical order.
I have write this code which sort the result of each thread but didn't sort the finale result.

```
public class Pdf extends Thread {

    File f;
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();

    public Pdf(File f, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.f = f;
    }
    ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {

            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().contains(".pdf")) {
                if (file.getName().charAt(0) >= 'a' && file.getName().charAt(0) <= 'z') {
                    Collections.sort(a);
                    a.add(file.getName());
                }

            }
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                new Pdf(file, file.getName()).start();

            }
        }
        Collections.sort(a);
        Collections.reverseOrder();
        for (String l : a) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have write this code which sort the result of each thread but didn't sort the finale result"-what do you mean not understand.

Comment: each thread return result , sorted and stored final output like: thread1 (aaa bbb ccc) , thread2(aaa bbb ccc) then the final is aaa bbb "ccc aaa" ... this is what i talking about

Answer (score 2):

When there is a directory then you are creating a new `thread`. That thread is calculating the files and add those in it's own local variable list. The list is sorted for one thread but as there are several different lists for different threads so you can't get a sorted result as a whole. Also as the different threads will be running separately so you can get random outputs of file names.

TO overcome this you can do either of the followings.

1. If you use separate thread like this then use a common concurrent list which can be sorted after all the threads are finished executing.
2. It is better to use a single thread. Here instead of creating a separate thread for each subdirectory, just create a method which will add the files in list and will recursively call itself when there is a subdirectory. In this case at the end of thread you can sort the list and print it.

Also one a different note if you want to reverse the list then you have to call `Collections.reverseOrder(a)`

Comment: If you want to manage this with multiple threads using the first solution StinePike suggested, please pay attention to the race condition of the file that different threads may write. Synchronize the access to the file that contains the list of the pdf file

Comment: yah .. And that would be a complicated one .. I prefer the second option unless OP want to explore multithreading

Comment: Not that difficult with `Collections.synchronizedList()`

Comment: multithreading is requested and necessary instruction in this project .. and Ph requste the Synchronize instruction so can you tall me how to use this instruction and sorted names after  all threads are finished.

Comment: dmbook.pdf gym-problems-2.pdf numerical analysis.pdf ssau-qual-2014-en.pdf statements (2).pdf statements.pdf syrian-collegiate-programming-contest-2014-en.pdf bitwise.pdf calculus_11_Sequences_and_Series.pdf contest-2663-en.pdf cp1.pdf download-pdf-ebooks.org-ku-16565.pdf intsqrt.pdf math.pdf prime.pdf probability.pdf search-2.pdf series_formulas.pdf shift.pdf pc2v9AdminGuide.pdf pc2v9JudgesGuide.pdf **this is a simple output of my code**

Answer (score 1):

You will need a collection that all threads will add their results to.  Make sure that that collection is a synchronized one.  Otherwise, the collection could "break".  Then, you must wait until all threads are finished.  Once they are, you must then sort the collection they added to and return that.

Comment: i don't know how to sort th collection after all threads are finished.@Andrew

Comment: Collections.sort(yourList);

Comment: More specifically,java.util.Collections.sort(yourList);

Comment: I had used this instruction in my code ... but the wrong is where I have to use it. @Andrew Cahill

Comment: You would sort the collection after you have waited on all threads to finish.